# Powershell Command to Copy Latest Version of Multiple Files

Tags: powershell

I am trying to do a restore of my OneNote notebooks but they restore process isn't ideal.  It stores copies of the notes and appends a date to them, and a number if there is more than one for each day.  I want to grab the latest file (note) and move it to a folder and then I can restore them instead of using their process.
[image]

I have tried using `gci | select last -1` which only gets me the latest file in the entire directory.  But I need each notes latest version.  Ideally, I would make a copy, dump it into another directory that matches the current directory name it is in, and get rid of everything after .one, but I would be happy with just a copy of each notes latest version in a directory.

Comment: `Get-ChildItem |Group-Object {$_.Name -split '\.one'|Select -First 1}`, then `Select -Last 1` on each group

Comment: This is the recommended restore process [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Restore-notes-from-a-backup-5daf9cb0-6769-4998-a5de-f044fdd0d831?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1).

Comment: Thanks for that.  I am not sure how to implement that last part "Select -Last 1" into the previous command but some of these files have a number after the date.  I don't think those would be the 'last one' in each group. "and a number if there is more than one for each day"

Answer (score 0):

This script can help you.

```
$dirPath = "<The directory where the files are located>"

Get-ChildItem $dirPath |
    Group-Object { ($_.Name -split '\.one' | Select-Object -First 1) } |
    Select-Object @{ Name = 'FileName'; Expression = { $_.Name } },
                  @{ Name = 'LastFileDate'; Expression = { ($_.Group -split ',') |
        ForEach-Object { [DateTime](($_ -split ' ')[2] -split '\)')[0] } |
            Sort-Object $_.LastFileDate |
            Select-Object -Last 1
    } } |
    ForEach-Object { "{0}.one (On {1:dd-MM-yyyy}).one" -f $_.FileName, $_.LastFileDate }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Mathias' suggestion, and expanding on it to get what you wanted (the most recently modified file in each group), here is a solution that should work for you:

```
$grps = Get-ChildItem | Group-Object {$_.Name -split '\.one' | Select -First 1}
foreach ($group in $grps) {
    $group.Group | Sort LastWriteTime | Select -Last 1 | Select Name, FullName, LastWriteTime
}
```

You can just grab the FullName property of each file there and use that to Copy-Item it somewhere else.